# Elliptic solution of Schrödinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The Schrödinger equation is

> $$i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x, t) =- \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta \Psi(x,t)+V(x)\Psi(x, t)$$

If $\Psi(x,t) = e^{-iEt}u(x)$, we will get a ground state equation. For this case, it is $S^1$ symmetric. But as I know, in gravitational field , the orbital can be a elliptic, so it  means the Schrödinger  equation should have elliptic symmetric solution, is it ?

What is elliptic symmetric: for the Schrödinger equation, it is an elliptic symmetric solution, if it has form solution $\Psi(x,t) = (a\cos Et+ i b\sin Et)u(x)$, where $a,b>0$ is constant.

Comment: How is $S^1$ symmetry applied to this equation? There is no ellipse here. Is $x\in R^1$ or $R^3$?

Comment: The potential $V(x)$, if considered as a gravitational potential, has surely an influence on the structure of the ground state solutions $u(x)$ and thus on $\Psi$: however, consider what happens for the [vibrating drum](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drum_vibration_mode12.gif), where the potential is the function $V_D$ which is $0$ inside the disk $D$ and $+\infty$ outside it. Even if the drum plate $D$ is circular, the eigenfunctions possess many more symmetries than the simple $S^1$.

Comment: What do you call an "elliptic symmetric solution" ? In the classical world, the trajectory is planar and has a three planes of symmetry. But one of them is accidental and will certainly not remain because only one focus is involved.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  I have add the definition of elliptic symmetric solution in above.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri  Thanks your example, I just want to know there are any paper about the elliptic symmetric solution of Schrödinger equation. Since not any potential can make it has symmetric solution.

Comment: So the symmetry you are searching for are to be considered respect to the time $t$:  unfortunately I am not aware of any study on such solutions.